# How to recieve metrics for Object Detection while using pytorch and Weights & Biases?

Tags: image-processing, pytorch, torch, wandb

I have been training and fine tuning few models for detection task on a custom dataset,
I would like to plot relevant metrics such as mean Average Precision (taking into account the predicted bounding box location and the enclosed object's classification).

I'm using Pytorch and have started using `Weights & Biases` ([Weights & Biases integrated with pytorch](https://youtu.be/G7GH0SeNBMA?list=PLD80i8An1OEGajeVo15ohAQYF1Ttle0lk))

For avoiding inventing the wheel, I have used some files from here:

https://github.com/pytorch/vision/tree/main/references/detection

`engine.py` - holds the **train_one_epoch()** function

`cocoeval.py` - holds the **summarize()** function

Now I would like to log those metrics to a `Weights & Biases`,
so I'll we able to get more clear view and intuition about the fine-tuning phase,but I'm not sure where is the proper place to put the logger invocation.
can somebody please assist me?

```
wandb.watch()
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To log your training metrics, within the `train_one_epoch` function, there is a `MetricLogger` class which currently logs some metrics in a basic way. To add W&B and get more powerful metric logging and visualisation, you can add `wandb.log` in place of the `MetricLogger`.

`wandb.log({'loss': losses_reduced, 'lr':optimizer.param_groups[0]["lr"]}`

https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/528651a031a08f9f97cc75bd619a326387708219/references/detection/engine.py#L56

Above you mention `wandb.watch`. If you intend on using that to track gradients, you would call it once when the model is initialised.

https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/528651a031a08f9f97cc75bd619a326387708219/references/detection/train.py#L222